# What can I do to fix this error when attempting to install active record for composer from github?

Tags: php, json, activerecord, github, composer-php

I create a JSON file called composer.json with

```
{
    "require":{"php-activerecord/php-activerecord": "dev-master"}
}
```

I then go to the folder in Terminal and type: composer install

I receive this fail message:

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                                            
  Failed to clone https://github.com/kla/php-activerecord.git, git was not found, check        that it is installed a  
  nd in your PATH env.                                                                                          

  sh: git: command not found
```

I have no idea what to do. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system does not find the command line command `git`.

Your options:

1. Install git for the command line.
2. Don't install "dev-master" of that library, but a tagged version instead.

The first one will make it work in general. The second one will avoid using git to download the source code, but a ZIP file of that version.

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you. That was the problem. I didn't realize that meant to install git for some reason.

Comment: For some reason its making me wait 5 minutes before I can accept.

Comment: Yes, this is to avoid users to instantly accept the first answer. Usually more answers might be given, and the best helping one should be accepted.